# Why do I get the value from mongodb.ObjectID in the wrong format (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, objectid

```
var id = new mongodb.ObjectID("545e2fa90293a69004414ae9");
var valid = ObjectID.isValid(id);
```

Why do I get this value it - `T^/©¦AJé`"?

Help me please!

Comment: Can you provide more information on the code that is not working. What variable returns the value?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `isValid()` function expects either a number or a string (12 or 24 characters). You are passing it an object, that's why it returns `false`. You need to convert the ObjectId object to a string:

```
var valid = ObjectID.isValid(id.toString());
```